# How can i filter values in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

Hi everyone how can i filter the values in angularjs?

- I have created plunker for reference :- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sz4ZkvdtvIonw5jdQ6BE?p=preview).
- I want to filter `user` `categories` in ng-repeat `question list page`

**User datas:-**

```
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "chennai",
"religion": "hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
},
```

- `categories` values are in array, i need to filter `categories` values only in ng-repeat list page....
- For Example:- if `user categories values` `"categories": [
  "Religion & Culture",
  "Social Psychology"
  ],` so these two values only should filter in list of category...

**My Html:-**

```
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:user.categories ">
    <small>
                    <span >{{$index + 1}}.</span>
                      <span data-ng-bind="question.category"></span>
                  </small>

  </div>
```

- I have used filter in ng-repeat like :- `| filter:user.categories`
- I want to filter user categories in repeat list...
- please check and update the plunker as well to know the exact solution...

Comment: what do you want to filter your list with? you need to have some data regarding `categories` I guess?

Comment: is this just a homework? what have you tried before post here?

Comment: @tanmay please look at my plunker i have user data like categories and i need to filter these categories in ng-repeat list, please check my plunker and update the same...thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom filter like:

```
.filter('filterCategory', [
 function() {
  return function(questions) {
   var filteredCategories = [];
   if (questions && questions.length) {
    angular.forEach(questions, function(question) {
      console.log(question)
      if(question.user && question.user.categories && question.user.categories.length){
        angular.forEach(question.user.categories, function(category){
          if(filteredCategories.indexOf(category)<0){
            filteredCategories.push(category);
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
   return filteredCategories;
 }
}

])
```

And then in the ng-repeat you need to write:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in questions| filterCategory ">
```

Comment: Yeah you can check this plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/wM65xfwxvdGHczAmTBHg?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer , please look at my plunker there are three `Religion & Culture` is available but yours plunker showing only one `Religion & Culture`...we need to filter all `Religion & Culture` and need to show number of `Religion & Culture` also...please check and help...thanks

Comment: Sorry you question in not quite clear to me, for each data there is a user object and then for each user there is a categories array. So you want to show all those categories in the list? I thought you want to show unique values.

Comment: yes exactly for each data there is a user object and then for each user there is a categories array, if authenticate user is signed into portal , authenticated user categories array should filter in that list...for example:- if `"displayName": "Table 1",` this user signed into portal this particular user categories only need to filter....please check my plunker...thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, then you can check my updated plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/wM65xfwxvdGHczAmTBHg?p=preview

Comment: thank you Indra you almost done...please once again look at my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Sz4ZkvdtvIonw5jdQ6BE?p=preview in the list there are various category is displaying, but the user has `Religion & Culture
and Social Psychology` categories,so what i am expecting just want to filter user categories in that `list` category, for example:- there four category is displaying in list, so filter should work based on the user categories, thanks indra... i have tried to filter like `| filter:user.categories "` in ng-repeat but it's not working for me so please check and help thanks....

Comment: Sorry your requirement is still not clear to me. You have a category for each question and then in each question there is a user and in the user there is a categories array. So you want to show the category in each question if that category is present in the categories array of the user for the same question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `filter: user.categories` try `filter: question.user.categories`

Comment: the above solution is not working for me, please check my plunker and update the solution thanks ...